# I need to show DATE box (do not hide after selection) in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, date, calendar

I need to show Date box (it should not be hidden after select day month and year).

i don't know how can i implement it in visualforce page.

just like below image.

[image]

I tried this code but it will hide after selection `<apex:input type="date" value="{!date}"/>`

my question is solved but NOW, i need standard calendar on my visualforce page.
Is it possible ?

Comment: I tried this code but it will hide after selection <apex:input type="date" value="{!date}"/>

Comment: If you don't wan't to hide after selection, then when it will close?

Comment: I have updated my solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nihar, if your question is solved and you want to ask a different question, please do not update your question but [ask a new question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doable using jQuery UI Date Picker.

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page id="myPage" docType="html-5.0" controller="TestJQDatePicker">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>

      var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
      $j(document).ready(function() {
          $j( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                  altField: "#myPage\\:myForm\\:DateValue",
                  altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
           });
      });

  </script>

  <apex:form id="myForm">
      Select Date: <apex:input type="date" id="DateValue" value="{!selectedDate}" /> <div id="datepicker"></div>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Output:
[image]

The date picker remains visible after the date is selected. Also note that `altField` parameter is used to define which input should get auto-populated with value after the date is selected. And `altFormat` is required as otherwise type="date" field rejects the default format of the date picker.

Hope this helps!

Comment: One more thing to note is that under the `altField` parameter, I had to escape the ":" using "\\" to specify the Id of the field that should receive the selected value. jQuery throws an error if the field id contains a colon.

Answer (score -1):

> Update

Sorry, I have not noticed the question carefully earlier. The question was to display the datepicker even after user clicks on the date. Yes you can do it by adding little javascript hack. What happens when user clicks on the date, the Salesforce js automatically hides the datepicker div. **What you have to do is to display the div again.** I have update my solution as below. Hope this helps.

**Updated Solution**

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="SampleDatePicker">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                Date 2 : <apex:inputText value="{!datename}" size="10" id="demo" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(false, this , false);" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>            
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("datePicker").addEventListener("click", displayDate);
        };
        function displayDate() {
            document.getElementById("datePicker").style.display = 'block';
        }    
    </script>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class SampleDatePicker {
    public String datename {get; set;}
    public SampleDatePicker() {

    }
}
```

**Previous Solution**

Salesforce has an inbuilt datepicker. You don't have to add JS library for this. Please find the code below. don't forget to add docType="html-5.0" in page tag like shown below

**Vf Page**

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="SampleDatePicker">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                Date: <apex:input type="date" value="{!dat}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class SampleDatePicker {
    public Date dat {get;set;}
    public SampleDatePicker() {

    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Yes but the OP needs the date picker to remain open after the date is selected.

Comment: @AAU Thanks for your comment. I have updated the solution.